# Perform Chi Squared Test for each group in a contingency table

Tags: r, statistics, chi-squared, contingency

I have a contingency table with the following data:

| Category | Group1 | Group2 | Group3 | Group4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C1 | 281 | 133 | 132 | 37 |
| C2 | 192 | 93 | 79 | 8 |

The task ist to compute in R a Chi Squared Test for every group in the table.
I'm completely new to R and have no idea how to do it. I somehow managed to come up with the snippet

```
apply(xtab, 2, function(x)
  chisq.test(matrix(x, ncol = 2)))
```

where the parameter xtab is the above mentioned table. This performs a Chi Squared Test on the groups, but the resulting x-squared values/p-values are looking wrong or I'm simply not able to confirm the computation manually.

Comment: Depends on what you want to do a bit as `chisq.test` can give several types of comparisons depending on the input. You have a 4 (groups) x 2 (categories) matrix here essentially, so you could do it all in one go once you drop the category label - `chisq.test(xtab[-1])` which would seem most logical to me as a test of the association between category and group. See something like: https://www.statology.org/chi-square-test-of-independence/ for some background details on what the test does.

Comment: Looking wrong is a rather vague description.

Comment: To get the four Chi Squares, `lapply(xtab[, -1], chisq.test)`. This tests the hypothesis that the two counts are equal. All four are significantly different. Note, that the full table `chisq.test(xtab[-1])` as suggested by @thelatemail  
is also significant, but the p-value is larger indicating that while C1 is consistently greater than C2, there is some difference by group.

Comment: @dcarlson Four tests? Why not 6? `combn(xtab[-1], 2, chisq.test, simplify = FALSE)`.

Comment: That would be more interesting, but the OP's code only compares the two values in each column, C1 == C2 for Group1, ....